# Launcher hides and when cursor is touching the edge

Tags: unity, 12.10, compiz, launcher

I've been using Ubuntu (and Mint) for almost two years (since Ubuntu 11.04 to be exact), and yesterday I decided to try some Compiz effects for a first time, never actually bothered about that.
Everything is fine now, I have enabled 3D cube, left click on bottom edge activates it.
Also, I've enabled wobbly windows and water effect.
But, here is my problem:
Since I enabled cube, my Unity launcher just hides back again one second after it's activated. Basically, as always i push cursor to the left edge of my screen, and if I keep on holding it on the edge it just hides back again.
If i after it's revealed move cursor to the right over the icons it stays until I click.
Sometimes this is very annoying because I have ~30 icons in launcher and when i start scrolling down they just hide...

I really hope you know what I'm talking about, maybe there is a obvious way to solve this but I didn't see it haha.

Comment: Uh sorry, didn't even notice. It's 12.10.

Comment: Hi, just add the 12.10 "tag" to your question in addition to unirt, compiz and launcher.

Comment: Seriously, anyone!?